# Is the NTRU Challenge still ongoing?

Tags: public-key, post-quantum-cryptography, ntru

In 2016, security innovation released the [NTRU challenge](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ntru-challenge-one-year-later-gene-carter).

I understand that NTRU is now patent free and it seems like most of the documents related to the NTRU challenge on security innovation's website are now not available. Is there an archive where I can access these documents? and is the NTRU challenge still ongoing? Is the largest parameter broken still N=173?

Comment: `The NTRU Challenge will continue to run throughout 2016.` Wayback machine?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160310143833/https://www.securityinnovation.com/products/encryption-libraries/ntru-crypto/ntru-challenge/solved-challenges.html